# How can I properly relate multiple BiMap collections using shared keys?

Tags: java, guava, bimap

I have the following BiMap collections:

```
BiMap<String,String> accessIds = HashBiMap.create();
accessIds.put("FOO","accessId 1"); //This access Id is common to both FOO and BAR

BiMap<String,String> merchants = HashBiMap.create();
merchants.put("FOO", "merchant 1"); //Both FOO and BAR each have unique merchants
merchants.put("BAR", "merchant 2");
```

These are 2 of the 4 total collections I currently have. All 4 collections share the same keys, but different values.

The question I have is: **How can I ensure that I can get `merchant 2` when I have an accessIds key of `FOO`?**

Before someone points out that these two collections do not, in fact, share the same keys, please remember that a BiMap enforces unique values so I am unable to list `"BAR","accessId 1"` in the collection.

I'm not convinced that BiMap is the right collection, but I do make use of its `inverse()` method. If there is a collection better suited ( or some other method that I am overlooking ) please let me know.

FYI: I use Guava-14.0-rc1 for the BiMap collection.

Comment: Tell us your use case, instead of a non-working solution. If several keys can have the same value in accessIds, obviously it can't be a BiMap. And why would FOO or BAR have precedence on the other if they share the same accessId? Why not use real objects?

Comment: @FrankPavageau In my other cases accessId's can be directly mapped to a specific value. My use case takes an Access ID, and then grabs several pieces of data from various collections to build the objects required to authenticate to various webservices. I didn't put any other specific information in as this snippet, because even though it doesn't represent real information,it serves to illustrate what I need to accomplish. As I stated in the question, I'm not convinced that BiMap is correct, so if you have another suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, in your workflow, the Access ID is a key, not a value, that in at least one case has several associated values instead of one.

You could use a [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) for your Access IDS, assuming you can then select which value to retain as the key for accessing the other `Map`s (or `BiMap`s, though it's unclear through your example why they *are* `BiMap`s, but I guess that's unrelated).

```
ImmutableMultimap.Builder<String, String> builder = ImmutableMultimap.builder();
builder.put("FOO", "accessId 1");
builder.put("BAR", "accessId 1");
ImmutableMultimap<String, String> accessIds = builder.build();
ImmutableMultimap<String, String> byAccessIds = accessIds.inverse();

Collection<String> keys = byAccessIds.get("accessId 1"); // ["FOO", "BAR"]
String key = doSomething(keys); // "BAR" is chosen
String merchant = merchants.get(key); // "merchant 2"
```

If you cannot use immutable structures, you can also build a regular `Multimap` for `accessIds` (for example using a [`HashMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html)) and inverse it using [`Multimaps.invertFrom()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M%29).